# Is the term "telescoping product" well known?

Tags: sequences-and-series, products

I know that "[telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)" (or [sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html)) is well known. But I can't find many reliable references to the term "telescoping product". It would be one of the following:

- $x_i = \dfrac{y_i}{y_{i+1}}$:
  $$\require{cancel}\begin{align}
  \prod_{i=m}^n x_i &= \prod_{i=m}^n\frac{y_i}{y_{i+1}}\\
   &= \frac{y_m}{\cancel{y_{m+1}}} \cdot \frac{\cancel{y_{m+1}}}{y_{m+2}} \,\,\cdots\,\, \frac{y_{n-1}}{\cancel{y_n}} \cdot \frac{\cancel{y_n}}{y_{n+1}}\\
   &= \frac{y_m}{y_{n+1}}
  \end{align}$$

or

- $x_i = \dfrac{y_i}{y_{i-1}}$:
  $$\begin{align}
  \prod_{i=m}^n x_i &= \prod_{i=m}^n\frac{y_i}{y_{i-1}}\\
   &= \frac{\cancel{y_m}}{y_{m-1}} \cdot \frac{y_{m+1}}{\cancel{y_m}} \,\,\cdots\,\, \frac{\cancel{y_{n-1}}}{y_{n-2}} \cdot \frac{y_n}{\cancel{y_{n-1}}}\\
   &= \frac{y_n}{y_{m-1}}
  \end{align}$$

It shows up in signal processing, for example, in a formula to compute the modified prediction errors of [RLS filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares_filter) non-recursively (reducing the numerical error). But I've never seen the term "telescoping product" in any bibliography. So would it be inappropriate for me to use that term without explaining what it means?

Comment: I think the meaning is clear.

Comment: I’m not sure in what context you’re considering using the term, but I agree with others that the meaning is clear. It would be fine, for example, to say “We can write this as a telescoping product: ...”

Comment: I'll chime in and agree with the other commenters. Perfectly understandable. The term is rather poetic in the first place, but has acquired general acceptance because it seems quite apt. The sum (or product, in this case) collapses like a telescope.

Comment: @SteveKass The context is: I want to just say something like "expanding the recurrence above as a telescoping product and solving it, yields:" without wasting lines to explain exactly how to cancel out the terms.

Comment: Sure, that would be fine, if you showed, or if it were quite obvious, how to rewrite the $i$-th term as a suitable fraction. “Telescoping” is a good way to communicate the idea of canceling pairs of adjacent numerator-denominator values, whether by subtraction (“sum”) or division (“product”).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a simple google search, many teaching resources use the term "Telescoping Sums and Products":

1. www.math.cmu.edu/.../3-telescope-solns.pdf (broken now, but from a reliable CMU edu website. Google says it is titled: III. Telescoping Sums and Products)
2. http://faculty.wwu.edu/sarkara/ph13.pdf (Title of paper is "Telescoping Sums and Products")

Regardless, I think I could figure out what you meant...