# Calculate the product limit by using elementary high school techniques

Tags: real-analysis

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{i=2}^n(1-{1\over{i+1 \choose 2}}) $$
This is a problem i have encountered in one of my textbooks.Solve it by using high school methods for real analysis.

Comment: The index $i$ does not appear in the expression.

Comment: Im sorry it was a misstype.

Comment: Hint: Simplify and factor. You will get a telescoping product.

Answer (score 3):

$$1-\binom{i+1}{2}^{-1}={(i-1)\over i}{(i+2)\over(i+1)}$$

So [telescope the product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055204/is-the-term-telescoping-product-well-known) to get $${1\over n}{n+2\over3}$$

Now taking the limit we get

$${1\over3}$$

Comment: i reached the same point but i couldnt simplify the product

Comment: $$\binom{i+1}{2}={(i+1)!\over2!(i-1)!}={(i+1)i\over2!}={i(i+1)\over 2}$$             Does that help? If you're confused about telescoping open the link in the post an read the question.